# Fit a line to 3d point cloud in R

Tags: r

I have point clouds (xyz-coordinates) that I need to fit a linear model to. I thought I'd use lm() for that.

This is what I tried:

```
library(scatterplot3d)

# example points
x <- c(1,4,3,6,2,5)
y <- c(2,2,4,3,5,9)
z <- c(1,3,5,9,2,2)

# plot    
s <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z, type="b")

# fit the model
ff = lm(z ~ x + y) ## in ff$coefficients are the line paramters z, mx, ny

# create coordinates for a short line (the fit) to plot
llx = c(min(x), max(x))
lly = c(min(y), max(y))
llz = c(
  ff$coefficients[[1]] + llx[1] * ff$coefficients[[2]] + lly[1] * ff$coefficients[[3]],
  ff$coefficients[[1]] + llx[2] * ff$coefficients[[2]] + lly[2] * ff$coefficients[[3]]
)

## create 2d coordinates to place in scatterplot
p0 <- s$xyz.convert(llx[1],lly[1],llz[1])
p1 <- s$xyz.convert(llx[2],lly[2],llz[2])

# draw line
segments(p0$x,p0$y,p1$x,p1$y,lwd=2,col=2)
```

Although, the red line looks convincingly like a fit I'm not sure it is. If you rotate the plot, it doesn't look very good.

```
for(i in seq(from=30, to=60, by=1)){
  s <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z, type="b", angle=i)
  segments(p0$x,p0$y,p1$x,p1$y,lwd=2,col=2)  
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

Is this just due to 2d projection of the line?!? Can you somehow update the coordinates? I tried to give the $xyz.convert() function an "angle" attribute, without luck.

Also, when I use only two example points the fit fails.

```
x <- c(1,4)
y <- c(2,5)
z <- c(1,3)
```

I'd appreciate a confirmation whether I use lm() correctly.
Thanks!

**[EDIT]**

I learned that lm() fitted a plane to the data based on the model I gave it (z~x+y). This was not what I wanted. In fact, I misunderstood lm() entirely. Also for 2d data. E.g. lm(y~x) tries to minimize the vertical space between fit and data. But, I wanted the data to be treated as completely independent (spatial data) and minimize the perpendiculars between fit and data (as first paragraph here: http://mathpages.com/home/kmath110.htm).

The answer marked as correct does exactly this. The principle is called "principal component analysis".

Comment: The regression use is correct. The problem is with plotting the regression line. The ordered pair  of `llx` and `lly` may not always correspond to the input. Like in above the ordered pair of `llx` and `lly` are `(1,2)` and `(6,9)`. Though you get `(1,2)` pair by luck, pair `(6,9)` is not a part of your input dataset. So you are getting incorrect regression line.  Solution is to  plot the regression line using the ordered pair of points in input dataset.

Comment: llx, lly are just the maximum extend of the example points. I think I coul also use llx = c(0,1000000000); lly=llx. But I use a shorter line. I get here llx = c(1,6) and lly = c(2,9). So, I think your answer does not address the problem, right?

Comment: Imagine a line corresponding the input model (not the line segment). Though the range may extend from `-Inf` to `Inf`. The line corresponds to particular triplet of `(x,y,z)` (In your case the input to the model and other similar inputs and output). You cannot expect the line to lie along all the triplets that possibly you can make using `x` and `y` taking independently and corresponding `z`. Then it will cover the whole of `2D plane`. `x` and `y `are related(corresponds to the same observation) is what I mean to say.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't know what the model (z ~ x + y) represents. I thought it's the 3d expression of something like y = mx + n for 2d lines. That's, where all the trouble starts ;) What would be the model for a linear fit to the point cloud?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lm(z ~ x + y)`'s fit points make not a line but a plane. Your segment indeed belongs to the plane.

```
s <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z, type="b")
s$plane3d(ff)
segments(p0$x,p0$y,p1$x,p1$y,lwd=2,col=2) 

# rgl
library(rgl)
plot3d(x, y, z, type="s", rad=0.1)
planes3d(ff$coef[2], ff$coef[3], -1, ff$coef[1], col = 4, alpha = 0.3)
segments3d(llx, lly, llz, lwd=2, col=2)
```

[image]

#### [EDITED]

What you want is to fit a line to 3-dimensional data, in other words, summarize 3-dim into 1-dim. I think the line consists of principal component analyze's 1st component (i.e., **mean + t * PC1**, this line minimizes total least squares). I referred to "[R mailing help: Fit a 3-Dimensional Line to Data Points](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Fit-a-3-Dimensional-Line-to-Data-Points-td863596.html)" and "[MathWorks: Fitting an Orthogonal Regression Using Principal Components Analysis](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-an-orthogonal-regression-using-principal-components-analysis.html)".

```
x <- c(1,4,3,6,2,5)
y <- c(2,2,4,3,5,9)
z <- c(1,3,5,9,2,2)

xyz <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
N <- nrow(xyz) 

mean_xyz <- apply(xyz, 2, mean)
xyz_pca   <- princomp(xyz) 
dirVector <- xyz_pca$loadings[, 1]   # PC1

xyz_fit <- matrix(rep(mean_xyz, each = N), ncol=3) + xyz_pca$score[, 1] %*% t(dirVector) 

t_ends <- c(min(xyz_pca$score[,1]) - 0.2, max(xyz_pca$score[,1]) + 0.2)  # for both ends of line
endpts <- rbind(mean_xyz + t_ends[1]*dirVector, mean_xyz + t_ends[2]*dirVector)

library(scatterplot3d) 
s3d <- scatterplot3d(xyz, type="b")
s3d$points3d(endpts, type="l", col="blue", lwd=2)
for(i in 1:N) s3d$points3d(rbind(xyz[i,], xyz_fit[i,]), type="l", col="green3", lty=2)

library(rgl)
plot3d(xyz, type="s", rad=0.1)
abclines3d(mean_xyz, a = dirVector, col="blue", lwd=2)     # mean + t * direction_vector
for(i in 1:N) segments3d(rbind(xyz[i,], xyz_fit[i,]), col="green3")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I understand what the model I use represents! But, yet I am not sure how to achieve what I'm looking for: a linear fit to the points... and also the r2 for that fit.

Comment: This also explains, why two points are not enough to fit this model!

Comment: I though it would be much easier, but this is what I needed. I thought it should be similar to lm(y~x) for the 2-d case. But apparently I was wrong... Thank you very much.

Comment: one last question. Can you show me how to calculate r2 of the fit?

Comment: @Toni; A concept of R square is under `y ~ x1 + x2 + ...`, such as `lm()`, so in your case it isn't. I think PC1's Cumulative Proportion (you can see it by `summary(xyz_pca)`) expresses the degree of fit.

Comment: Thanks. My lack of statistic knowledge is embarassing ;)